# Tabs not rendering when knitting rmarkdown to html

Tags: html, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I've been using rmarkdown and knitr to create html output. Quite suddenly, the `{.tabset}` function seems to have stopped working when knitting, and documents render as they would without this option.

Here is a simple example that does not work as it should on my system.

````
---
title: "Plot Tabs"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
``` 

## Title {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

### tab 1

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

### tab 2

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I've tested this on another system, and it works fine. I've also reinstalled R and updated all my packages as well as RStudio.

Does anyone know of any similar issues, or anything that could be causing the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. R 3.4.0_gcc-4.9.1, pandoc 2.0.2, and rmarkdown 1.8

Comment: Curious pandoc 2.0.2 fails to make tabs, pandoc 1.15.0.6 works just fine...

Comment: I was using pandoc 1.19.2.1, but have updated to 2.0.5 and still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is [a known bug](https://community.rstudio.com/t/3019) and has been [fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/7663afa87bfc93590fa84bf587375bee9dfa4efd) in the current development version of **rmarkdown** on Nov 21, 2017. Please test the development version:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me, but I needed to remove and reinstall the yaml package prior to installing the dev version of rmarkdown.