# tabset not creating tabs in Rmarkdown

Tags: tabs, r-markdown

I have come across the same problem as in this post, where .tabset suddenly stopped working:
[Tabs not rendering when knitting rmarkdown to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639445/tabs-not-rendering-when-knitting-rmarkdown-to-html)

I don't understand how to use devtools to download latest version of markdown, and anyway this was an old post and I'm pretty sure I do have the latest version (2.1), isn't there another way to install it? which one is the right version? Or could there be another reason it's not working?
It worked fine on my office computer but now I can't access it as I'm working from home, and I'm very confused.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

EDIT: I also tried this on RStudio Cloud, so the problem seems to be with some package version, not my computer, but I don't have a clue what to do about it

EDIT 2: another puzzling thing, if I copy paste code from the post I linked to, it works! but when I write my own (exactly the same way) it doesn't, and all my old files also don't work. But I'm having trouble posting the code here because the hashtags and code chunks break the flow... how do I make this stay within one chunk of code?

````
---
title: "Plot Tabs"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
``` 

## Title {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

### tab 1

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

### tab 2

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

If it helps, the message I get at the end of knitting is:

> output file: test2.knit.md
>
> "C:/Users/Agata/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test2.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output test2.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\Agata\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\Agata\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGm8blg\rmarkdown-str232057c511a8.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --lua-filter "C:/Users/Agata/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/Agata/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua"
>
> Output created: test2.html

FINAL EDIT: it *seems* that this was partly caused by not putting spaces after hashtags, which is perhapsa a requirement in the new markdown version , although I'm still getting the weird message at the end. My session info is:

````
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3```
````

Comment: Show us your code ... you´re right, version 2.1 is the current stable version.

Comment: works perfect for me ... What is your `sessionInfo()`?