# How to ensure tabset contains the correct data

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

The goal is to create a a page in Rmarkdown that contains two tabs each displaying different information. After over a dozen different tries I've decided it makes sense to ask since the closest I've gotten as shown in the image is two tabs both showing the same information. Not sure what it is I'm missing. I've searched a couple other questions and none of them address the issue.

This is the code that I have tried so far

````
---
title: test
output:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    self_contained: false
---

Page
========================

## Try {.tabset}

### Tryto
```{r}
  cat(paste("WORDSSSSS"))
```

### Work
```{r}
  cat(paste("WORDSSSSSqqqqqqqqq"))
```
````

I included the single quotes here since it was messing with how things were displayed in SO so please remove.

[image: Current Output]

Desired out put would have "WORDSSSSS" under the "Tryto" tab and "WORDSSSSqqqqqqqqqq" under "Work".
Thanks!

EDIT:
packages
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added the single quotes so that SO didnt interpret the ``` as the identifier that i wanted to have it be in code format in the code i am running there are no single quotes.

Comment: I just copied/pasted your code and it works for me as is (without the single quotes). Also, there are several ways to post questions of R Markdown, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-within-in-line-code-in-markdown).

Comment: I'm wondering...what version of packages are you using for R Markdown, pandoc, etc.? Maybe copy/paste your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I might consider trying to update packages including rmarkdown. Are you using R Studio? R Studio automatically includes pandoc. You can also copy/paste your code in [RStudio Cloud](https://rstudio.cloud/) to try that environment. I read other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639445/tabs-not-rendering-when-knitting-rmarkdown-to-html) about problems with `tabset` in R Markdown that may have been addressed with upgrading packages. Gotta run will check in later...

Comment: I am using r studio server version 1.1.463. Based on what i found its the most updated version

Answer (score 0):

---

title: "Test"

output: html_document

---

## Try {.tabset}

### Tryto

```{r}
 
cat(paste("WORDSSSSS"))

```

### Work

```{r}
  
 cat(paste("WORDSSSSSqqqqqqqqq"))

```

Comment: ignoring the larger document this is what i have. I will edit the code to show markdown initialization