# Tabsets are not rendering in knitted rmd files

Tags: r-markdown

First time I've encountered this problem, no idea how to approach it.
I've un/re-installed R and RStudio a handful of times and I'm still encountering the same problem, even after using the remotes package to install the latest development version of `rmarkdown` .

````
---
title: "Missing Tabs"
output: html_document
---

## Tabset here {.tabset} 

### tab1

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

### tab 2

```{r}
summary(pressure)
```
````

Produces:
[image]

Session info:

```
> devtools::session_info()
- Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2020-07-11                  

- Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 backports     1.1.8   2020-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 devtools      2.3.0   2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fs            1.4.2   2020-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 glue          1.4.1   2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgbuild      1.0.8   2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 processx      3.4.3   2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ps            1.3.3   2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 remotes       2.1.1   2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rstudioapi    0.11    2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 xfun          0.15    2020-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)

[1] C:/Users/ed/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library
```

Not sure how to troubleshoot this, would appreciate any steps in the right direction.

Comment: I get tabs, that is weird you do not. Maybe try clearing your R environment
`rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
gc()`

Comment: Tried clearing the env, have also tried restarting the R session. Super odd problem that I'm not sure how to troubleshoot, especially since it's just happening on my PC and I can't provide a reprex

Answer (score 0):

What about

````
---
title: "Missing Tabs"
output: html_document
---

# Tabset here {.tabset} 

## tab1

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## tab 2

```{r}
summary(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Same problem unfortunately

Comment: what if you did `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639445/tabs-not-rendering-when-knitting-rmarkdown-to-html) to reinstall the github version

Comment: Tried this before earlier. Tried again by uninstalling and reinstalling the above version. Still no luck!

Comment: what about using a different browser, what does it look like in Rstudio viewer? very unusual. Maybe even try looking for updates with your OS? I bet if you used another computer it would work

Comment: Yes definitely works on other computers. Tried deleting everything related to R, running updates etc to no avail. Looked the same on RStudio viewer and all browsers. I ended up just reinstalling Windows haha, well it worked and problem solved but the mystery remains.