# Knitr is ignoring tabs in HTML theme

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am new to R markdown and tried to use it on my computer at work. However, I was not able to change the theme or add tabs. On my personal computer, however, everything works and I get pretty HTML documents.

I used the markdown document that opens every time you open a new document. I changed the html theme to lumen and included tabs:

````
## I want tabs {.tabset}

### Tab 1

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

### Tab 2

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

#{-}
````

Here I have some screenshots of the tab sections:

**My laptop**:

[image]

---

**My computer at work**:

[image]

my computer at work is not able to create the Tabs and is als not changing the font if I change the theme... If someone has suggestions on how to fix this, that would be great!

EDIT: Could it be an issue with the path? Since IT installs R for all computers the Pathvarible instead of "C:/Programms" is "\user01\User\username\Programms" I set the global PATH of R Studio to "C:/..." but if I knit the document in R Markdown, it still uses the weird path for the library path...

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to just write a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that. You can try to remove and re-install the yaml package and see if it helps.

But it would be good to get more information from you. Do you have an older version of R in your working computer? Apparently this was a known bug back in 2018. See [Tabs not rendering when knitting rmarkdown to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639445/tabs-not-rendering-when-knitting-rmarkdown-to-html). In this case the problem was solved by re-installing the yaml package and installing the dev version of Rmarkdown `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`.

**Edit**: Trying using package flexdashboard

````
---
title: "My tabs"
author:
output:
   flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

## I want tabs {.tabset}

### Tab 1

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
### Tab 2

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Good luck!

Comment: I have the same version of R on both computers. I will try to reinstall and report back.

Comment: Any luck, @CST?

Comment: HI ViviG. No.. but I think I now found the problem. It now started complaining about "the path is not valid" So I think it is because IT installed it not locally but for everyone. But I still dont know how to solve the issue.. I changed the path in the global settings, but the error remains..

Comment: You can try to do it with fleshdashboard to see if it helps? I edited my answer. Otherwise I read in a forum somewhere that someone only got this to work by re-installing Windows...

Comment: I now tried with fleshdashboard. it does not work... I just get a document that says "Title" but nothing to klick or open

Comment: Do you use projects in R? I have problems using R in my work laptop outside work, so all my projects are in my OneDrive. This solves the issue for me.

Comment: I use projects.. but I created 2 scripts. one on my laptop and one at work, they are identical and both inside their project folder which is also the working directory of R

Comment: If you think the problem is coming from the path, I would move the project to a cloud storage like OneDrive, Dropbox, etc. I have the same issue with the "weird path" if I put my project anywhere other than in a cloud storage.

Comment: I cant move the data I plan to analyse with the final script. Also.. the path of the library seems to be the problem, since this still starts with the weird "user" part..